# $\hat q \hat p$-quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantization

I'm looking through the [Berezin's paper 1971](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01036576). And there are a couple of question that confuse me.
It's clear why we need to use quantization procedure, because of the uncertainty principle and discrete nature of observables.
So, in the paper the classical observable are written in a polynomial form:
$$f(q,p) = \sum f_{m_1, ... m_n, m_1', ... m_n'}(p^1)^{m_1}...(p^n)^{m_n}(q^1)^{m_1'}...(q^n)^{m_n'}$$
and corresponding quantum operator according to $\hat q \hat p$ - quantization is
$$\hat f = \sum f_{m_1, ... m_n, m_1', ... m_n'}(\hat p_1)^{m_1}...(\hat p_n)^{m_n}(\hat  q_1)^{m_1'}...(\hat q_n)^{m_n'}.$$
But why is it supposed that every classical value can be exactly represented as a polynomial? What about the non-liner terms, like $sin$, $cos$?  For example if there is a potential energy that results from the EM wave nature and has the form $E_0 \sin(\omega t-xt)$  or even a Coulomb's potential?

Comment: Berezin is merely looking at polynomials for simplicity. He is not claiming that all quantum operators correspond to  polynomials.

Comment: @Qmechanic Could you clarify what class of observables does he aim at, while using polynomials operators, please?

Comment: As with the case of matrices and lots of operators, functions thereof are, at the very least, meant to be schematically represented by their Taylor series.

Comment: Got it thank you